# About cocos2d-x applicationWillEnterForeground

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

On cocos2d-x's game. When I pressed the home button to quit the game. The next time, how can I  make the game must start over again, but not followed by the last exit scene

Answer (score 0):

Ideally in `applicationWillEnterForeground` you should simply replace the scene with a new instance of it to start over e.g. if the class of scene you were running is called `GameLevelScene` you should simply tell `CCDirector` to replace the running scene with a new instance from it's class. For example:

```
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->replaceScene(GameLevelScene::create());
```

But while I was doing something similar to pause my game on resuming from background I noticed that it wasn't quite working (it should've, maybe this is some problem with cocos2d-x). So, as a work around, I created a sequence with a delay time of zero at it's start and then called my game's pause function. I guess the game needed to take one tick to process this after resuming from background. For you, if the above doesn't work just try this:

```
someNode->runAction(
    CCSequence::create(CCDelayTime::create(0.0f),
        CCCallFuncO::create(CCDirector::sharedDirector(),
                            callfuncO_selector(CCDirector::replaceScene),
                            GameLevelScene::create()),
        NULL));
```

`someNode` can be any node in your game which is **living** in the game i.e. it hasn't been destroyed; it must be an alive object. You can have a game manager node which is alive at all times during your game. The game manager node can be made responsible for such game management issues.